# Как реализовать паузу при переходе между сценами?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задача следующая, по нажатию кнопки с клавиатуры (у меня это Esc) необходимо ставить игру в сцене 1 на паузу и открывать сцену 0 с меню.

Сделать не сложно, но возникает проблема, когда возвращаюсь из меню в игру (со сцены 0 на сцену 1) - прогресс в игре теряется - игра стоит на паузе, но в самом своем начале (в точке запуска).
Вот что сейчас есть:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
         {
             Pause();
         }     
    }
    void Pause()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет исправить...

Answer (score 3):

Это нужно реализовать не через сцены. Вызов меню должно реализовываться как остановка времени игры `Time.timeScale = 0f;`

и показывание канваса на котором отрисовывается меню.

Comment: Или через подгрузку дополнительных сцен `SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive );`

Comment: в отдельной сцене есть смысл размещать только главное меню(что б оно прогружалось быстро, вместо загрузки тяжеловесного игрового уровня). Но никак не те меню, которые вызываются в процессе игры